# Clases with partiarly shared Propeties, Methods. How to avoid duplication of code?

Tags: c#, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have three classes: `InputSocket`, `InternalSocket`, `OutputSocket`. They all inherit from `BaseSocket` with implements `ISocket` interface, where I have common code for all classes and this part works fine, I have problem with partially shared code.

`InputSocket` and `InternalSocket` shares Parsing part with `OutputSocket` does not have.

`InputSocket` and `OutputSocket` shares GUI part with `InternalSocket` does not have.

I'm looking for a way to share common parts of code between `InputSocket` / `InternalSocket` and `InputSocket` / `OutputSocket`. Code with consist of methods and parameters. 
I already tried using multiple interfaces but it didn't solve the problem, well it made it a little more manageable. When I create `IParsable` for *parsing part* and `IExternal` for *Input/Output common part*, then I need to create `IParsableSocket` for `InternalSocket` `IParsableExternalSocket` for `InputSocket` and `IExternalSocket` for `OutputSocket`. It does not change the point that I still need to implement code for every case, with leads to code duplication.

Unfortunately there is no way for `InputSocket` to inherit from `OutputSocket` and `InternalSocet` at the same time in c#.

Is there an alternative, to copy/paste of code or making an general Socket class with bunch of if logic and nulls?

Comment: In general, this situation usually means that you use inheritance wrong. It really depends on why you want `GUI` to be in your socket, but most probably, you need to go for [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), or extract this functionality to separate class at all, or use extension methods.

Comment: If all of the members in each socket class really belong there, then consider creating an interface for each shared functionality. This will not save on lines of code, but will help when passing sockets to particular functions.

On the other hand, perhaps the functionality does not belong in sockets directly. Maybe GUI is its own class that some socket types should reference or that should instead reference a socket. 

It's more important to get the functionality modeled correctly than it is to reduce the lines of code.

Comment: Implement a `ParsingProvider` and a `GUIProvider` and use composition.

Comment: I will try to solve this using composition. @N-ate GUI is where it belongs, question was simplified in reality all those classes belong to GUI, and `InputSocket`/`OutputSocket` common part is just GUI data they share, and `InternalSocket` does not have.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think `inheritance` is the right solution for you here. You should not have methods in your interface which you do not intend to use/ implement in your inherited class. This is violation of [Interface Segregation Principle](http://In%20the%20field%20of%20software%20engineering,%20the%20interface-segregation%20principle%20(ISP)%20states%20that%20no%20client%20should%20be%20forced%20to%20depend%20on%20methods%20it%20does%20not%20use.[1]%20ISP%20splits%20interfaces%20that%20are%20very%20large%20into%20smaller%20and%20more%20specific%20ones%20so%20that%20clients%20will%20only%20have%20to%20know%20about%20the%20methods%20that%20are%20of%20interest%20to%20them.%20Such%20shrunken%20interfaces%20are%20also%20called%20role%20interfaces.[2]%20ISP%20is%20intended%20to%20keep%20a%20system%20decoupled%20and%20thus%20easier%20to%20refactor,%20change,%20and%20redeploy.%20ISP%20is%20one%20of%20the%20five%20SOLID%20principles%20of%20object-oriented%20design,%20similar%20to%20the%20High%20Cohesion%20Principle%20of%20GRASP.[3])

> The interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should
>   be forced to depend on methods it does not use

In your case, it means `BaseSocket` should NOT be a God class having all the "common" methods. Instead you would need multiple interfaces and implementation which does one specfic operation, for example, `Parse` and `Gui` in your case.

Your different `Socket` classes then get `Composed` of those behaviour/ operations instead of `inhert`ing. This is known as [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

> Composition over inheritance in object-oriented programming is the
>   principle that classes should achieve polymorphic behavior and code
>   reuse by their composition rather than inheritance from a base or
>   parent class. This is an often-stated principle of OOP, such as in the
>   influential book Design Patterns.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

(You should suffix with base, not prefix with base)

So you have:

```
public class InputSocket : BaseSocket { }
public class InternalSocket : BaseSocket {}
public class OutputSocket : BaseSocket {}
public abstract class BaseSocket : ISocket { }
public interface ISocket {}
```

> InputSocket and InternalSocket shares Parsing part with OutputSocket does not have.

```
public interface IParsingSocket {}

public class InputSocket : BaseSocket, IParsingSocket  { }
public class InternalSocket : BaseSocket, IParsingSocket  {}
public class OutputSocket : BaseSocket {}
```

> InputSocket and OutputSocket shares GUI part with InternalSocket does not have.

```
public interface IParsingSocket {}
public interface IGUISOcket {}

public class InputSocket : BaseSocket, IParsingSocket, IGUISOcket  { }
public class InternalSocket : BaseSocket, IParsingSocket  {}
public class OutputSocket : BaseSocket, IGUISOcket {}
```

Implementation using Extension Methods:

```
public static class IParsingSocketExtensions
{
  public static void Parse(this IParsingSocket) {}
}

public static class IGUISOcketExtensions
{
  public static void DoGUI(this IGUISOcket) {}
}
```

Now you can

```
var inps = new InputSocket();
var ints = new InternalSocket();
var outs = new OutputSocket();

inps.Parse() // valid
ints.Parse() // valid
outs.Parse() // invalid

inps.DoGUI() // valid
ints.DoGUI() // invalid
outs.DoGUI() // valid
```